# java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer where is the problem in my code?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

```
  } else {
                Toast.makeText(EarningsActivity.this, "Minimum to Withdraw : "+minToWithdrawShared.getInt("minToWithdrawShared", 0) + currencyShared.getString("currencyShared", ""), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
```

when i click in this button (request withdrawal) the app stop and make exit
i try many times to resolve this but always wrong

the result in (run)

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.test.quizv3, PID: 8985
    java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
        at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.getInt(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:273)
        at com.test.quizv3.Activity.EarningsActivity$3.onClick(EarningsActivity.java:415)
```

Comment: Toast.makeText(EarningsActivity.this, "Minimum to Withdraw : "+Integer.parseInt(minToWithdrawShared.getInt("minToWithdrawShared", 0)) + currencyShared.getString("currencyShared", ""), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
I hope this solve your problem.

Comment: It looks like you're storing it as a String and reading it as an int.  But without a [mre], there's no way to know for sure.